# Неверен реляционный оператор в цикле. Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Создан цикл, который проверяет состояние базы, точнее, момент, когда она получит статус 0 (Онлайн). Если статус не получен, цикл уходит в ожидание. Но при запуске возникает ошибка:

ORA-00920: неверен реляционный оператор
ORA-06550: Строка 5, столбец 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

**Код:**

```
Use master
declare t_state number;
BEGIN
while 1=1
LOOP
    select "STATE" into t_state from SYS.DATABASES@DBLINK where "database_id=5";
    if t_state=0 /*0 - онлайн*/ then exit;
    end if;
    sys.dbms_lock.sleep(30);
END LOOP;
END;
```

**В чём кроется моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо**

Comment: `where` условие там точно в кавычках надо указывать?

Answer (score 0):

Если сильно нужно писать названия столбцов в кавычках, то попробуйте написать:

```
 where "DATABASE_ID"=5;
```

Comment: Опробовал, теперь по какой-то причине равно не ожидалось: Error report -
ORA-06550: Строка 5, столбец 12:
PLS-00103: Встретился символ "=" в то время как ожидалось одно из следующих:

   := . ( @ % ;
Символ "; был вставлен перед "=" для продолжения.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"